# How can I easily develop C# in Ubuntu (without monodevelop)

Tags: linux, c#, ubuntu, ide, .net

I almost always develop in a linux environment, but recently I've had to move to C#.

I know monodevelop exists, but I'd like to not use monodevelop for certain reasons.

Are there any other tools available on ubuntu for developing in C#?  If I google search this, I get about 20 pages of monodevelop posts.  I'm working in .NET 4.5.2.

I know I could just go to windows, but I'm trying to avoid that for now.  Thanks,

Comment: What's bad exactly with MonoDevelop? What are your exact requirements?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with MonoDevelop, I was just trying to figure out if something else exists.  My only requirements are that you can run .NET 4.5.2, and it's an IDE that isn't MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always reluctant to offer suggestions of non-free software for Linux, but depending on your academic situation or the nature of the project, you might be able to get free or cheap the JetBrains Rider IDE (https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/).

It's essentially the Jetbrains IDEA platform specifically geared around C# development, mainly focused at Unity development but nothing that can't be extended to other projects.

If free is the key, then Consulo (https://github.com/consulo/) might be useful, it's a forked version of IDEA that has more language support within it. Not as fancy, but a good alternative to MonoDevelop at least.

Comment: I don't believe Rider IDE will use .Net 4.5.2 on linux. Most likely, it will end up using Mono. Just like Visual Studio for Ma.